# How can I use AJAX to refresh a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to get a table to update from my database. I have been trying to follow a php guide as it thought it would be quite similar but I can get it to work.

I have a separate file That gets the data and puts it into a table. Then im trying to use Javascript to get the file and refresh it.

This is my main file.

```
<module template="../includes/header.cfm"  pagetitle = "Jaguar Live Capture">   
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
     <h1>Live Capture</h1><br />
     <h2>Pen 1</h2>
     <div id="tableHolder"></div>

    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
```

This is my getData.cfm

```
    <cfquery name="liveFeed">
SELECT * FROM details LIMIT 0, 10   
</cfquery>

    <style>
    .oddRow{background:#ffffff;}
    .evenRow {background: #DBDBDB;}
    .warn{background:red;}
    </style>

<table cellpadding="2">
<cfoutput query="liveFeed">

     <cfif liveFeed.currentRow mod 2><cfset rowstyle = "oddRow">
    <cfelse><cfset rowstyle = "evenRow">
    </cfif>

    <cfscript>
    if (liveFeed.form_id == "" || liveFeed.first_name =="" || liveFeed.surname =="" || liveFeed.email ==""){ rowstyle = "warn";}
    </cfscript>

    <tr class="#variables.rowstyle#">
        <td onclick="window.open('update.cfm?form_id=#liveFeed.form_id#', 'Update Details', 'width=350, height=350'); return false;">#liveFeed.form_id#</td>
        <td onclick="window.open('update.cfm?form_id=#liveFeed.form_id#', 'Update Details', 'width=350, height=350'); return false;">#liveFeed.title#</td>
        <td onclick="window.open('update.cfm?form_id=#liveFeed.form_id#', 'Update Details', 'width=350, height=350'); return false;">#liveFeed.first_name#</td>
        <td onclick="window.open('update.cfm?form_id=#liveFeed.form_id#', 'Update Details', 'width=350, height=350'); return false;">#liveFeed.surname#</td>
        <td onclick="window.open('update.cfm?form_id=#liveFeed.form_id#', 'Update Details', 'width=350, height=350'); return false;">#liveFeed.email#</td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

I have Tried a few pieces of javascript and ajax but have had no success. Can anyone help me create the script to refresh the page.

Comment: Do you have the option of using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function(){$('#tableHolder').load('/getData.cfm');}, 6000);
</script>
```

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is used to fire our anonymous function every 60 seconds.

The anonymous function uses the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to get a files HTML from the server and replace the selected elements HTML with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `cfdiv` tag to manage the AJAX request for you:

```
<cfdiv id="tableHolder" bind="url:getData.cfm" />
```

You could then use the [ColdFusion.navigate](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=JavaScriptFcns_24.html) function to reload or change the URL of that div.

```
ColdFusion.navigate('getData.cfm', 'tableHolder');
```

Comment: So this would refresh the table? Also would I be able to set a timer?

Comment: I wish I could +1 this answer, but I don't think recommending any of the CF client-side features is a good idea.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean :). It's quick, and dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very simply with jQuery load().  load() will make an async request to the page and then load the response into the specified element.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#tableHolder').load('getData.cfm');
});
</script>
```

Trying copying the above into your page.